# Cannot install package via pip on Raspbian

Tags: python-2.7, pip, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, dronekit-python

I'm trying to install two packages I need to connect my Raspberry Pi to a Pixhawk Flight Controller. The packages I need are installed via pip, but I keep on getting the same errors when attempting to install. Can any Python/Raspbian expert please suggest some solutions or decode the error for me.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install pymavlink
    enter code hereTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

As far as I know I have already successfully installed all the dependencies, which are listen here:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install screen python-wxgtk2.8 python-matplotlib python-opencv python-pip python-numpy python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libxslt1-dev' instead of 'libxslt-dev'
libxml2-dev is already the newest version.
libxslt1-dev is already the newest version.
python-dev is already the newest version.
python-matplotlib is already the newest version.
python-numpy is already the newest version.
python-opencv is already the newest version.
python-pip is already the newest version.
python-wxgtk2.8 is already the newest version.
screen is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Found what seems to be a solution in a different thread:

First remove the package from the package manager:

# apt-get remove python-pip

And then install the latest version by side:

# easy_install pip

(thanks to @Aufziehvogel, @JunchaoGu)